# Gorm many to many self reference using composite key

Tags: postgresql, go-gorm

I have the following model

```golang
type TenantUser struct {
    TenantID  uint      `json:"tenantId" gorm:"primaryKey; uniqueIndex:idx_name_and_tenant; uniqueIndex:idx_email_and_tenant"`
    UserID    uuid.UUID `json:"-" gorm:"primaryKey; type:uuid"`
    ...
    Visited  []*TenantUser `json:"visited" gorm:"many2many:visitors; foreignKey:TenantID,UserID; references:TenantID,UserID; joinForeignKey:visitor_tenant_id,visitor_user_id; joinReferences:visitee_tenant_id,visitee_user_id"`
    Visitors []*TenantUser `json:"visitors" gorm:"many2many:visitors; foreignKey:TenantID,UserID; references:TenantID,UserID; joinForeignKey:visitee_tenant_id,visitee_user_id; joinReferences:visitor_tenant_id,visitor_user_id"`
}
```

Which results in the following sql being generated

```sql
create table visitors
(
    visitor_tenant_id bigint not null unique,
    visitor_user_id   uuid   not null,
    visitee_tenant_id bigint not null unique,
    visitee_user_id   uuid   not null,
    primary key (visitor_tenant_id, visitor_user_id, visitee_tenant_id, visitee_user_id),
    constraint fk_visitors_tenant_user foreign key (visitor_tenant_id, visitor_user_id) references tenant_users,
    constraint fk_visitors_visited foreign key (visitee_tenant_id, visitee_user_id) references tenant_users
);
```

I don't understand why `visitor_tenant_id` and `visitee_tenant_id` are defined as unique. But more importantly, how can I prevent it?

If I execute code like the line below, with different visitors, only the first one is added. Doing it again just does nothing. It doesn't even give an error. If I manually delete the unique indexes from from the database everything works as expected.

```
db.Model(&visitee.TenantUser).Association("Visitors").Append([]*model.TenantUser{visitor})
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Did you try to set TenantID to regular index instead of unique?
`json:"tenantId" gorm:"primaryKey; index:idx_name_and_tenant; index:idx_email_and_tenant"`

Comment: I did and it worked but I need those indexes. I guess I have to restructure my model

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `uniqueIndex` tags from the `TenantID` field in your `TenantUser` struct and then regenerate your database schema.

```
type TenantUser struct {
    TenantID  uint      `json:"tenantId" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    UserID    uuid.UUID `json:"-" gorm:"primaryKey; type:uuid"`
    ...
    Visited  []*TenantUser `json:"visited" gorm:"many2many:visitors; foreignKey:TenantID,UserID; references:TenantID,UserID; joinForeignKey:visitor_tenant_id,visitor_user_id; joinReferences:visitee_tenant_id,visitee_user_id"`
    Visitors []*TenantUser `json:"visitors" gorm:"many2many:visitors; foreignKey:TenantID,UserID; references:TenantID,UserID; joinForeignKey:visitee_tenant_id,visitee_user_id; joinReferences:visitor_tenant_id,visitor_user_id"`
}
```